# Make file_get_contents() return server response despite HTTP errors

Tags: php, http, facebook-graph-api

If using file_get_contents() to connect to Facebook,

```
$response = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/...?access_token=***");
echo "Response: ($response)\n";
```

And the server returns a non-OK HTTP status, PHP gives a generic error response, and suppresses the response. The body returned is empty.

```
file_get_contents(...): failed to open stream: HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
Response: ()
```

But if we use cURL, we see that Facebook actually returns a useful response body:

```
{"error":{"message":"An active access...","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}}
```

How can I make file_get_contents() return the response body regardless of HTTP errors?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use `stream_context_create()`:

```
$ctx = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array (
        'ignore_errors' => TRUE
     )
));


file_get_contents($url, FALSE, $ctx);
```

Comment: This is poorly documented and confusing PHP feature - not returning response on errors - why? Responses contain reason of failure.

Comment: @lubosdz I agree with you

Answer (score 1):

You could ignore the errors file_get_contents throws

```
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'ignore_errors'=> true,
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$file = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/...?access_token=***', false, $context);

var_dump($file);
```

Comment: ha didn't notice. Thanks! And a +1 back at ya ;)

Comment: thx :) I must admit that I had to look into the manual to find this out.. Nice to have that `ignore_errors` option. Otherwise `file_get_contents()` would be less usable....

Comment: totally agree. Adding the stream context makes `file_get_contents` way more usable! Still prefer `curl` for these types of requests though :)

Comment: I prefer `file_get_contents` as it is the most portable way. Also on the console I prefer wget.. But beat me I know that `curl` is amazing. And we had some situations where curl was more stable than wget... So I should use it but I still use good old wget ;) ....